# Como desfocar imagem no css sem vazar?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Gostaria de aprender como desfoca uma imagem sem vazar no Wordpress - 
Veja o exemplo

[image: Foto: Conteúdo do Yahoo]

Como que faz!

Comment: O que vc quer dizer com "*sem vazar no wordpress*"?

Answer (score 1):

Pode utilizar duas imagens, uma com *blur* e outra sem, com uma `div` para inserir seu texto, veja:

```css
.conteudo {
     width: 70%;
     height: 70%;
     border: 2px solid;
     border-radius: 20px;
     position: fixed;
     top: 15%;
     left: 15%;
     z-index :10;
     background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
 .bg {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background-image: url('https://spguia.melhoresdestinos.com.br/system/fotos_local/fotos/27924/show/jardim-botanico-de-curitiba.jpg');
     z-index: 2;
     position: fixed;
}
 .blurred {
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     display:block;
     background-image:url('https://spguia.melhoresdestinos.com.br/system/fotos_local/fotos/27924/show/jardim-botanico-de-curitiba.jpg');
     z-index:1;
     position:absolute;
     top:-20%;
     left:-20%;
     padding-left:20%;
     padding-top:20%;
     -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
}
 .mascara {
     width: 70%;
     height: 70%;
     position: fixed;
     top: 15%;
     left: 15%;
     z-index:10;
     overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
<div class="mascara">
    <div class="blurred"></div>
</div>
<div class="conteudo">
<center><h1>Visite Curitiba!</h1></center>
</div>
```

Comment: Mas é no wordpress, no tema